# Devexpress schedule form

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, devexpress, schedule

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlaIx.png)

I try to use devexpress ( schedule Winform) but I don't know how to control a form that be auto generated after I double click on row inside schedule. Please give me a keyword or a solution for control this form ( Add more items, Remove exist items, etc...). Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the SchedulerControl's [EditAppointmentFormShowing](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl.EditAppointmentFormShowing) event to customize the display of the form.

The following DevExpress GitHub project demonstrates adding custom fields to the appointment form: https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-use-custom-appointment-fields-in-a-custom-editing-form-e2782

To create a custom appointment form and register it with the control, follow the directions in the [Custom Appointment Edit Form](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2949/controls-and-libraries/scheduler/getting-started#custom_form) documentation.